# How to specifically choose a key and value to store in array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I want to just store in `result` values from `key 'code'` instead of all including `'name' and 'id'`

Here is the code:

```
  <?php

$array = array(
array(
    "name" => "a",
    "code" => "416",
    "id" => "a1"
),
array(
    "name" => "a",
    "code" => "522",
    "id" => "a2"
),
array(
    "name" => "b",
    "code" => "580",
    "id" => "b1"
)
);

$counts = array_count_values(
array_map(function (array $entry) { return $entry['name']; }, $array)
// or array_column($array, 'name') in PHP 5.5+
);

$uniqueNames = array_keys(
array_filter($counts, function ($count) { return $count == 1; })
);

$result = array_filter($array, function (array $entry) use ($uniqueNames) {
return in_array($entry['name'], $uniqueNames);
});

print_r($result);
```

Try this to see the result : http://3v4l.org/32JUL#v530
What I want is: store `"code" : "580"` only instead of all sets.

Comment: You only want `code => 580` or you want an array containing all codes? It's not clear..

Answer (score 0):

I improved this one, because there might be possibility to get more ['code'] values with unique ['name'] , [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) would not be in best fit here. I would apply a simple foreach to get desired result.

```
$array = array(
array(
    "name" => "a",
    "code" => "416",
    "id" => "a1"
),
array(
    "name" => "a",
    "code" => "522",
    "id" => "a2"
),
array(
    "name" => "b",
    "code" => "580",
    "id" => "b1"
)
);

$counts = array_count_values(
array_map(function (array $entry) { return $entry['name']; }, $array)
// or array_column($array, 'name') in PHP 5.5+
);

$uniqueNames = array_keys(
array_filter($counts, function ($count) { return $count == 1; })
);

$result = array_filter($array, function (array $entry) use ($uniqueNames) {
return in_array($entry['name'], $uniqueNames);
});

foreach ($result as $res){  
    $uniqueCodes[] = $res['code'];
}
print_r($uniqueCodes);
```

Comment: without using loop? I need just to get the key(code) and its value from result.

Comment: key($result['code']) will give key literal. If in loop then strval($key) will give literal.

Comment: The result returns always array with single element?

Comment: using my code above. how would I get the `code` only for the array set ? have you tried runnning my code?